# Match regex up to first space

Tags: regex

I have to populate a shop's images and been provided with folders of images which arein the format, eg `BRL0368 Side.jpg`, `5510 Dura Guard Carpet.jpg`.

Now what I want to do is chop all those down so I can just try and match up in excel the part numbers eg `"BRL0368.jpg"`, `"5510.jpg"`

I have something called regex renamer which takes a regex match & a replacement value - and will recurse through a folder etc and batch rename.

Unfortunately at the moment I don't have much expereince with regex so it's a bit confusing for me - I tried many different options but not having much luck.

How do I say grab the first part (alpha & digit) up to the first space and dump the rest?

this is what I have been trying `([^\s]+)` - I also tried `\w` etc.

Comment: `\w+` should work for you. In what language do you want this solution?

Comment: Thanks for everyones help - I can see how understanding regex alot more will speed alot of things up for me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may depend on the language used, but this should work :

```
/^[^\s]+/
```

To capture the first word and the last (the extension) you can use this expression :

```
/(^[^\s]+).*?(\.\w+)$/
```

Here's a javascript demo to clear things up : http://jsfiddle.net/eDB2z/1/

Comment: Thanks for the demo, that's helpful on the regex tool page they have this kind of thing as a exmaple ;Match pattern:  ^img00(\d+)_sshot(_thumbnail)?
Replace pattern:      tutorial$2.$1

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need: 
`\w*(?= )`

Comment: Hi - this seems to have some effect, only thing is it returns say;5510 dura guard carpet.jpg (returns = " Dura Gaurd Carpet.jpg") - what I'm after is say "5510.jpg" - I tried ^ at the beginning to match the first word - if I have that right ?

Comment: In your question, you didn't say you need to leave the `.jpg` part

Comment: BTW You can run my regex and programatically take first match only + file extension.

Comment: Sorry about that - Interestingly - when I stick this in ^(\w*(?= )) and then put $1. in the replace pattern - it splits the words up but still doesn't get rid of the unmatched (5510. dura guard carpet.jpg) - It seems the match pattern is working then, just the replace / or the way I'm using the tool ?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, this helped me undertsand regex a little more.